# 400 Invalid_request You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5, facebook-ios-sdk, google-developer-tools

I am getting this error when I am trying to register with Google in my IOS app. I have got the REVERSED-CLIEND_ID which looks like something like this: **com.googleusercontent.apps**..... So far I can open the google window and I get the 400 error.

AppDelegate:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application,didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.restorePreviousSignIn { user, error in
            if error != nil || user == nil {
                // Show the app's signed-out state.
            } else {
                // Show the app's signed-in state.
            }
        }
        return true
    }
    
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
            app,
            open: url,
            sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
            annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]
        )
        var handled: Bool
        
        handled = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.handle(url)
        if handled {
            return true
        }
        
        // Handle other custom URL types.
        
        // If not handled by this app, return false.
        return false
    }
}
```

ViewController:

```
    let signInConfig = GIDConfiguration.init(clientID: "REVERSED_URL_THING")

  @IBAction func googleRegister(_ sender: UIButton) {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(
            with: signInConfig,
            presenting: self
        ) { user, error in
            guard error == nil else { return }
            guard let user = user else { return }

            // Your user is signed in!
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone came across the same issue, in Xcode's URL Types add **iOS URL scheme** and **do not use reversed url** like it was said in many tutorials. Use the CLIEND ID which Google provides:

```
let signInConfig = GIDConfiguration.init(clientID: "CLIENT ID ")
```

Comment: I'm developing in Flutter so don't really know my way round Xcode.  Found URL Types under Targets > Info, but what do I put in for Identifier, URL Scheme, Icon and Role?